# PHP - Receive JSON from Dialogflow Parse to URL

Tags: php, json, webhooks, dialogflow-es

Trying to create a php script which will receive JSON from Dialogflow webhook.

The data then needs to be parsed and

```
<?php
$input = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
$messageId = $input["resolvedQuery"];
$text = print_r($input,true);
file_put_contents('output.txt', var_export($text, TRUE));
$url = "https://autoremotejoaomgcd.appspot.com/sendmessage?key=APAue83jLrt7xFeQoGjgKq&message=" . $messageId;  

    $data = array("result" => "resolvedQuery");
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    $data_string = json_encode($messageId);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array("resolvedQuery"=>$data_string));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,
               array('Content-Type:application/json',
                      'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))
               );

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
?>
```

The data i need is from resolvedQuery but im not getting any output.

Would someone point me in the right direction please

Comment: where are you expecting output?

Comment: How is this script being called? Its looking on input for raw json input, but if whats calling this script is not doing that... your problem is there. Not here.

Comment: iv not coded before and trying to make a script on dialogflow.. i want it to receive json data from webhooks and then output it the JSON to my URL... i have been looking at tutorials online but cant seem to find anything to help.. here is my JSON {
  "id": "4d098ba0-1efe-40c7-bc37-0eba2857d6ad",
  "timestamp": "2017-12-08T19:10:39.325Z",
  "lang": "en",
  "result": {
    "source": "agent",
    "resolvedQuery": "turn livingroom lights on",
    "action": "",
    "actionIncomplete": false,

    i want resolvedQuery to be sent to my url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So from my understanding, you want *resolvedQuery* from api.ai in your webhook. All you  need to do is change:

```
$messageId = $input["resolvedQuery"];
```

to

```
$messageId = $input['result']['resolvedQuery'];
```

Check and tell me if it's working. I did skype, fb, and google integrations in php so if you need any help feel free to ask.

Comment: hi, thanks for coming back, i have managed to do it by adding result in the code... just a quick question i have it sending $messageId to "https://autoremotejoaomgcd.appspot.com/sendmessage?key=APAue83jLrt7xFeQoGjgKq&message=" . $messageId;..... how do i get it to send it to https://joinjoaomgcd.appspot.com//v1/sendPush?text=***NEEDED HERE***&deviceId=ac13ce6dd... Where needed here is i need messageId there but when i add . $messageId nothing gets sent. i hope you understand what im trying to say lol

Comment: I'm gonna have to see the code for you sending it to ** joinjoaomgcd.appspot.com//v1/sendPush?text=***NEEDED HERE***&deviceId=ac13ce6dd..** Please post it as another question and give me the link so I can check it. Also please mark this answer as accepted so this can be closed.